# Can close of pipe's write end fail leaving reading process blocked?

Tags: c, pipe, posix

Let's consider a common scenario

1. Create a pipe and fork (assuming no error happens)

   ```
   pipe (pipefd); fork();
   ```
2. A parent process writes to pipe, closes it and waits for its child

   ```
   write(pipefd[1], str, strlen(str);
   close(pipefd[1]);
   wait(NULL);
   ```
3. The child process reads from pipe until EOF

   ```
   while ((len = read(pipefd[0], buf, BUF_SIZE)) > 0)
       write(STDOUT_FILENO, &buf, len);
   close(pipefd[0]);
   exit(len == 0 ? EXIT_SUCCESS : EXIT_FAILURE);
   ```

Calling `close(pipefd[1])` on parent can potentially fail with an error due to some reasons. What will happen on the child's end in this case? Should child also receive read error or can remain blocked on the `read` call? Can this code lead to a dead lock (child on `read`, parent on `wait`) in this case? What is a correct way to handle this situation?

Comment: The parent process should close the read end of the pipe.  It isn't going to use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a preliminary matter, you do not describe the child process closing `pipefd[1]`. All else notwithstanding, the child must do that before it can expect its `read(pipefd[0])` calls ever to report an EOF condition.

> Calling close(`pipefd[1]`) on parent can potentially fail with an
> error due to some reasons.

Yes, in general, and in the sense that `close()` may return -1 and set `errno`.  But that does not necessarily imply that the file descriptor was not closed.  This is a tricky situation.  You should read the NOTES section of [the close(2) manual page](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/close.2.html) for a discussion, which is too long to reproduce here.

> What will happen on the child's end in this
> case? Should child also receive read error or can remain blocked on
> the `read` call?

It depends.  There is no answer at the level of generality at which the question is posed.

On some systems, such as Linux, `close()` *always* closes the specified file descriptor, provided that it is initially a valid, open file descriptor, even in cases where it ultimately reports an error.  On such systems, it is likely, but not guaranteed, that the child's `read()` would not, then, block indefinitely.

> Can this code lead to a dead lock (child on `read`,
> parent on `wait`) in this case?

If the parent ignores a failure to `close()` the write end of the pipe?  Yes, the child continuing to block on `read()` is within the possibilities allowed by POSIX.  If the parent then proceeds to `wait()`ing on the child then that could deadlock.

> What is a correct way to handle this
> situation?

If `close()` fails then the parent should report an error in some way -- diagnostic message, exiting with a failure status, or returning an error code, for example.  It could consider also trying to force the child to terminate by, for example, sending it a `SIGTERM` or even a `SIGKILL`.  Even without killing the child, you have to assume in this case that there may have been data loss or corruption, so killing the child does not make you any worse off in that regard.

Comment: If `close()` fails, there is essentially nothing you can do.  If the error is EBADF, you tried to close something that was not open.  For any other error, you can't reliably use the descriptor.  There is not much in point trying to close it again.